# Constructing clopen sets inside a normal space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a space satisfying $T_1$. Show that if $X$ is normal, then for any two disjoint closed sets $A,B\subseteq X$ there exist closed sets $A',B'\subseteq X$ such that $A\cap A'=\emptyset$, $B\cap B'=\emptyset$ and $A'\cup B'=X$.

My attempt: Assume $X$ is normal. Then for any disjoint closed sets $A,B\subset X$, there exist open sets $U,V\subseteq X$ such that $A\subseteq U$, $B\subseteq V$, and $U\cap V=\emptyset$. So now we need disjoint closed sets $A',B'$ such that $A'\cup B'=X$, but I can't figure out how to construct them, unless we have clopen sets, which again I don't know how to construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take $A' = X \setminus U, B' = X \setminus V$. Then $A \cap A' = B \cap B' = \emptyset$ and $A' \cup B' = (X \setminus U) \cup  (X \setminus V) = X \setminus (U \cap V) = X$.

Comment: Oh, I was stuck on $A',B'$ being disjoint but I just realized they don't have to be. Duh. My bad.

Comment: @mrose No they don't. $A',B'$ is called a *screening* of $A,B$.